# SQL how to exclude rows only if two conditions are met

Tags: sql

How do you write a where clause to exclude rows only if two things are true? For instance, I want the inverse of

```
SELECT * FROM table
where 
start_num = end_num
 and time_taken < 100
```

So I only want to return values where the start_num does not equal the end_num, but only if the time_taken is greater than 100. Both those two things have to be false to remove rows.

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM table
where (start_num <> end_num and tripduration > 100)
```

but that doesn't seem like it gives me the right number of rows in return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can simply use:

```
where not (start_num = end_num and time_taken < 100)
```

Note that this is not *exactly* the same, because this also filters out values where any of the column have `NULL` values.  It can easily be tweaked to handle that, if necessary.

This logic can also be written as:

```
where start_num <> end_num or time_taken >= 100
```